# Capturar informação e utilizar quando necessitar Java

Tags: java, objetos, instanciar-objeto

Estou a pensar em implementar um função que capta o usuário logado, ainda não imagino como posso implementar tal função, gostaria de saber o que é usual e propicio para que eu registre o nome e o código do usuário enquanto o software executa. Minha aplicação é feita em Java.

Comment: Quando o usuário se logar você pode jogar ele na sessão `HttpSession sessao = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);`, se a sua aplicação for web. 
da uma lida aqui [httpsession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caso sua aplicação seja web, essas informações são geralmente guardadas na sessão da aplicação. Veja aqui uma boa explicação sobre sessões:

http://klauslaube.com.br/2012/04/05/entendendo-os-cookies-e-sessoes.html

Caso sua aplicação seja desktop, você pode guardá-la em um Map que é acessado publicamente, como um singleton e sincronizado. Veja a seguir a definição de singleton:

http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton

**Session**

Veja a seguir um exemplo usando HTTP Session para servlets:

```
....
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
....



@WebServlet("/MyServlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
....


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        // recupera a sessõa
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        // colocar um valor na sessão
        session.setAttribute("user", "Pankaj");

        ....

        // recupera valor da sessão
        String userName = (String) session.getAttribute("user");

        ....

    }

....

}
```

**Desktop**

Veja uma classe que poderia ser usada para uma sessão Desktop:

```
package com.myapp.session;


import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;

public class Session {

    // note that HashTable is synchronized
    private Map<String, Object> _map = new Hashtable<String, Object>();

    private static Session _session = new Session();

    public static Session getSession() {
        return _session;
    }

    public void setAttribute(String key, Object value) {
        _map.put(key, value);
    }

    public Object getAttribute(String key) {
        return _map.get(key);
    }
}
```

Daí, para utilizar a sessão faça o seguinte:

```
Session session = Session.getSession();
....
// coloca um valor na sessão
session.setAttribute("user", "Pankaj");

....

// recupera valor da sessão
String userName = (String) session.getAttribute("user");
```

Comment: ok, Eduardo tem algum exemplo que posso imaginar para começar a bolar como vou fazer? Obrigado

Comment: Sua aplicação é web ou desktop? Se for web, que tecnologia você está utilizando?

Comment: minha aplicação é Desktop

Comment: Veja agora que você tem um exemplo de como utilizar sessões para servlets e como criar e utilizar sessões para aplicações Desktop.

Comment: Caso a resposta esteja correta, por favor de um "tick" na seta verde logo abiaxo da pontuação da questão. Obrigado :)

Comment: Eduardo acabei de testar aqui e funcionou muito obrigado pelo help abraços.